# Mongo Yelp Data Set Nested JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Hi I am trying to run a query on following collection but running into problems. The collection is called checkin and is from Yelp's data set challenge.

```
"_id": ObjectId("563434343434343"),
"checkin_info" : {
   "1-0":1,
   "2-0":2,
   "3-1":2,
   "23-1":6,
   "20-6":2
 },
"type" : "checkin",
"business_id" : "1234"

"_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
"checkin_info" : {
   "3-2":1,
   "4-0":2,
   "7-1":2,
   "22-1":4,
   "21-3":1
 },
"type" : "checkin",
"business_id" : "1235"
```

"1-0" : 1 means there were 1 check-in on 1:00 on Sunday, 3-1 means 3:00 on Monday , 20-6 means 20:00 on Saturday and so on.

I am trying to find for each business_id number of checkins for each day of week. I am not sure how to do it because the day and hour are part of a single key. Do I break them before importing data into database or is there some other way.

Secondly, I am also having issues in selecting like below

```
db.checkin.find( { 'checkin_info.10-4' : "2" } );
```

I do not know how to access the keys "10-4","12-5". Maybe I am missing some quotes etc. Can you please tell me how to navigate to these keys.

Comment: The aggregation framework cannot traverse the keys of an object, so mapReduce is the only option unless you transform the data seperately. The aggregation framework is native code, so it will run faster than mapReduce. Also as noted the structure is not great for general queries, but `$where` can evaluate JavaScript conditions. So it's generally up to you whether to live with slower analysis and JavaScript based logic, or endure the cost of pre-processing the data to a more logical structure for your desired queries/aggregations

Comment: So I would sort out how you decide to handle the data first. Either keep it as is or transform. Then questions about how to query/aggregate become a bit more focused.

Comment: I have to use both the MapReduce and Aggregation and compare the performance. Can you please tell me the answer to second part where I am not able to traverse the nested field in find() function. How do I access it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. I think the point is that with a structure like this the "query" basically needs to specify the paths explicitly, just as you did. As a general question, I don't really see a definitive question, since you are basically musing on which is best to do. If anything there is the *"I am trying to find for each business_id number of checkins for each day of week."*, but until you make the decision to keep data like this or tranform it then the only answer is how to do that in it's present form.

Comment: In present form, you use mapReduce. `Object.keys(object)` is the general JavaScript notation to get keys to traverse. But the "decision" seems to be the important thing here. I don't see the point of an involved mapReduce operation if you do choose to change the data. Also there is little point in describing processing an alternate structure without a solid structure or knowledge of how you want to use it.

Comment: Hi I am still looking for how to access the key that is a number. What syntax shall I use

    db.checkin.find( { 'checkin_info.10-4' : "2" } ) this does not work
    db.checkin.find( { checkin_info[10-4]: "2" } ); neither this
    db.checkin.find( {checkin_info:{'10-4' : "2" }} ); nor this

how do i run find() on the key "10-4"

Comment: Well I don't see a "10-4" value in the example data. `db.checkin.find({ "checkin_info.1-0": 1 })` works just fine as expected. Perhaps it is because you are using the "string" `"2"` rather than the numeric value `2` which the data actually is.

Comment: oh it works I was using "2" instead of numeric value. Thank You for your help. I will now run a map reduce on this.